# Best control panel for Ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: server, software-recommendation, vps

I am looking for up-to-date control panel that is compatible with 12.04 and easy to install. Most of the open source control panels I've seen have been out of development for years now. zPanel looks up to date, but I've had an impossible time installing it.

Comment: ssh + bash + tmux  usually works for me..

Comment: This question is not very fitting with our "Supported by Facts" system here, because there's no "best" control panel for this, and it's a highly subjective question.  We can recommend a list of control panels, but we can't tell you what is or is not the best.

Comment: For users searching for server control panels, this other question may help: [What server control panels are available for Ubuntu Server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333529/what-server-control-panels-are-available-for-ubuntu-server)

Comment: The question is always what is best for me, for this project. That's why I maintain a list of every last control Panel I can find. http://lordmatt.co.uk/item/2429/

Answer (score 4):

http://www.ispconfig.org/ispconfig-3/

**ISPConfig 3** is an open source hosting control panel for Linux which is capable of managing multiple servers from one control panel. ISPConfig is licensed under the BSD license.

http://www.webmin.com/

**Webmin** is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix. Using any modern web browser, you can setup user accounts, Apache, DNS, file sharing and much more. Webmin removes the need to manually edit Unix configuration files like /etc/passwd, and lets you manage a system from the console or remotely. See the standard modules page for a list of all the functions built into Webmin, or check out the screenshots.