# What server control panels are available for Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, administration, vps

As a dedicated Ubuntu server or as a VPS, I am looking for a web control panel, something like cPanel which is something like a web administrator for a server.

I have not used any on Linux since I do everything through the terminal, but still want to know what I can use in the case I have to recommend Ubuntu Server with such an application installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best control panel for Ubuntu 12.04 server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/181230/best-control-panel-for-ubuntu-12-04-server)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu that question is closed :-(

Comment: @guntbert It can be open :-)

Comment: Yes I had already read that other one, but in my case I created this question since that one was not clear what it wanted. Was it only open source ones, is it only easy to install or the best one. I am looking for control panels in general that can work in Ubuntu without constraints to which one I would like to see. I am certain I can manage any of them if given a chance and looking for the best one would be opinion based.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a list of free and paid control panels that are available for Ubuntu server

> **Free CPanel Alternatives**
>
> **[web://cp](http://www.web-cp.net/)**
>
> web://cp was where it all seems to have started for much of the open
>   source world. It was written in php and the aim of it's single
>   developer was to make a good quality control panel.
>
> web-cp is an Open Source solution taking up the torch where web://cp
>   stopped and is a direct continuation of that project. Like the
>   original this is written in php and so should put little additional
>   stress on a server. This might be good for you if your server is a
>   little lacking in the power needed to run piles of additional
>   software.
>
> **[FlexCP](http://flexcp.sourceforge.net/)**
>
> FlexCP is an Open Source solution and so is likely to improve in
>   proportion to the number of users. It can be obtained under the GNU
>   GPL version 2 from sourceforge.net. It is a redevelopment of
>   "web://cp" and as of writing had not released any file packages.
>
> **[Cube Panel Lite](http://www.cubepanel.com/)**
>
> This is the stripped down version of the non-free Cube Panel. Being
>   closed source there is a lot less that can be easily researched on the
>   subject. I can however tell you that you will be limited to one server
>   and 30 domains. After that yo will be looking for an upgrade or
>   another free alternative.
>
> **[VHCS](http://www.vhcs.net/)**
>
> VHCS is an open source solution released under the Mozilla Public
>   License 1.1 (MPL 1.1) and it appears to be a live and ready to go open
>   source solution. For mission critical servers this might be the choice
>   of system for this reason only. It is a sourceforge.net project so
>   downloading should be simple even if installation is not.
>
> And of course
>
> **[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)**
>
> Webmin is a free and impressive looking suit of control panel
>   packages. It is free and open source solution licensed under the BSD
>   License according to sourceforge.net. Much like the Fedora and Red Hat
>   relationship there is a non-free version too. The GNU GPL is also used
>   which is a bit confusing for the fussy.
>
> **Non-Free CPanel Alternatives**
>
> **[Plesk](http://www.plesk.com/)**
>
> After CPanel this is possibly the next biggest system used.
>
> **[Cube Panel](http://cubeworldforum.org/topic/8795-release-cwmyadmin-1204-web-control-panel-for-cubeworld-servers-windowslinux/)**
>
> While "not at all" playing off the CPanel naming this is a
>   commercially viable package. Like CPanel there are three levels of
>   management allowing for reseller accounts but also like CPanel you are
>   going to pay for this. The key advantage here is that you an get a
>   free 20 day trail version to test out prior to purchase. You may also
>   find that the "lite" version has everything you need.
>
> [**Ensim pro**](http://www.ensim.com/)
>
> **[Direct Admin](http://www.directadmin.com/)**
>
> While "not a free offering" the lifetime unlimited license is a mere
>   US$299 which, right now, is arround UK£147 (give or take a bit). This
>   comes with 90 days of support which should be enough to get you up and
>   running. Alternatively you can pay by the month for ongoing support.
>
> **[Virtualmin Pro](http://www.virtualmin.com/taxonomy/term/49)**
>
> The pay for, super "pro" version of webmin's virtualmin for those that
>   want all the power. The webmin site says "Both the Pro and GPL
>   versions are built from the same codebase, so all bugfixes and some
>   new features go into both of them."
>
> [**VHCS Pro**](http://www.vhcs.net/)
>
> **[ServerPilot](https://serverpilot.io/)**
>
> ServerPilot is a SaaS control panel for developers hosting their
>   websites on Ubuntu servers. The basic server configuration and
>   security functionality is free. The paid plans offer advanced
>   features and monitoring.

<sup>Source:[LordMatt](http://lordmatt.co.uk/item/966/)</sup>

Comment: Are you saying that webmin is supported again in Ubuntu? [This question on launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/2873) and [Webmin Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebMin) say otherwise.

Comment: @guntbert According to their [downloads Page](http://www.webmin.com/download.html), the latest release 1.640 is available for download for Ubuntu.

Comment: After reading bug reports there (no **serious** Ubuntu/Debian issues) I am *almost* convinced - remain two points: 1) Are *we* willing to give support with webmin problems?  2) I just found: for **upgrading** packages they use 'apt-get -y install' (see [bug 4079](http://sourceforge.net/p/webadmin/bugs/4079/).

Comment: I should point out that the article that Mitch used from my blog is really old, like 2007, old. There is a 2011 updated list but for the most comprehensive you want this one which is brand spanking new: http://lordmatt.co.uk/item/2429/ I should also point out that I've not specified which systems work on which OS as there seems to be a CentOS or Debian/Ubuntu divide many times but maybe you can find additional solutions not listed here?

Comment: @MatthewBrown  I thank you very much for the updated info.  I sure that it will help.

Comment: @Mitch - you're welcome mate. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **ISPConfig** in my staging development server since years and works just fine!. It's actively developed and really easy to install and use. It allows you to select between nginx or apache webserver, and also has support for several PHP versions. It has control of users, domains, resellers and even virtual machines!

It has a very comprehensive free support channel through HowToForge forum https://www.howtoforge.com/community/#ispconfig-3.23 and site https://www.howtoforge.com

You can find more here http://www.ispconfig.org/page/home.html

Here is a **very** detailed installation procedure for **Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04**

- If you plan using **Apache** https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-apache2-php-mysql-pureftpd-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3
- If you plan using **nginx** https://www.howtoforge.com/the-perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-nginx-bind-mysql-php-postfix-dovecot-and-ispconfig3

In the documentation page of the project you will find lots of other setup instructions for other distros http://www.ispconfig.org/page/en/documentation.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: ++ for the only free viable option thus far, active and modern, seeming to support Ubuntu 15.04 and even [Softaculous](https://www.softaculous.com/docs/Installing_Softaculous_in_ISPConfig).

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend you to try **ISPmanager**.

- [Features & Pricing](https://www.ispsystem.com/software/ispmanager-en/features)

Yeah, it's not free but price is much lower than for cPanels.
The panel has all features that premium panels has. It's even has buil in PHP selectro, which is actually really usefull.

Business version has integration with CloudLinux, so you can provide stable shared hosting with it!

What's more intresting is that this panel has only one price for both VPS and Dedicated Server, so you won't overpay if you uses phisical server.

GUI is pretty simple, you could see it by using Live Demo or checking [snaphot of the panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlE56.png).

Answer (score 0):

Vhcs should be reached here, http://vhcs.sourceforge.net/ The other link is old.  And cube panel is not available no more.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment to Mitch's answer, but alas not enough reputation.

I have another that can be added, it has free and paid versions:

**[Webuzo](http://www.webuzo.com/)**

> Webuzo is a Single User Control Panel which helps users deploy Web
>   Apps (WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, etc) or System Apps (Apache, NGINX,
>   PHP, Java, MongoDB, etc) on their virtual machines or in the Cloud.
>   Webuzo enables you to focus more on using applications rather than
>   maintaining them. Webuzo is also available in the form of Virtual
>   Appliances.