# Web Interface for Firewall?

Tags: firewall

Is there any web based firewall available for Ubuntu servers
which offers options like this one:

[image: web-based firewall gui]

Answer (score 4):

You need to install some control panel software as [VestaCP](http://vestacp.com/features/) оr [Webmin](https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Linux_Firewall):

- VestaCP:

[image]

- Webmin

[image]

---

Here is a list of **free control panels** alternatives:

- [web://cp](http://www.web-cp.net/)
- [FlexCP](http://flexcp.sourceforge.net/)
- [Cube Panel Lite](http://www.cubepanel.com/)
- [VHCS](http://www.vhcs.net/)
- [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)
- [VestaCP](http://vestacp.com/)

Here is a list of **paid control panels** alternatives:

- [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/)
- [Cube Panel](http://cubeworldforum.org/topic/8795-release-cwmyadmin-1204-web-control-panel-for-cubeworld-servers-windowslinux/)
- [Ensim pro](http://www.ensim.com/)
- [Direct Admin](http://www.directadmin.com/)
- [Virtualmin Pro](http://www.virtualmin.com/taxonomy/term/49)
- [VHCS Pro](http://www.vhcs.net/)
- [ServerPilot](https://serverpilot.io/)

---

Sources:

- [What server control panels are available for Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333529/what-server-control-panels-are-available-for-ubuntu-server)
- [Installing features on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860247/installing-features-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks You. But i am looking for one which only offers Firewall. I already have VestaCP installed on my other server but as for this one i am looking for something that offers advanced Firewall options like Blocking Packets Containing Subtring as seen in picture in post.

Comment: @FaqahatFareed It would be nice to post an answer if you find any suitable application.